# jQuery DataTables inline editing of empty fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

So far this is my set-up of `DataTables` used in my own app:

[image]

But the input fields are not that UI-friendly or pleasing to look at. And so I happen to stumble upon this feature of `DataTable`, which is [Inline Editing](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple), and now instead of those unpleasant-looking input fields, **I want to have the fields similar to the Inline Editing functionality of Data Tables, with the exception that there are no values "to be edited", just empty fields with placeholder texts.**

Is that even possible? I tried to trace the example and it seems to make use of some `DataTable.Editor`, but I can't seem to grasp how to implement an **empty field** one instead of a **"editable field with default contents"** (like the examples found in the documentations).

Any help? Also, if appreciated, I'd like to have the **Total Load** to automatically be computed whenever the **No. of Units** and **Power Rating** is filled up. It is simply the (No. of Units * Power Rating).

**Here's my initial code setup:**

- The `table.js` contains the initialization of the `DataTables`,
- whilst `globs.js` contains the ajax query with the corresponding creation of rows in the table.

I just pasted the codes that are relevant to my questions, and disregarded the others (jQuery actions of the buttons and etc)

### table.js (Initialized jQuery codes)

```
$(function() { 
   var table = $('#costcenter_table').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": 4,
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false,
                "sortable": false,
                "width": "75px"
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

### globs.js (contains functions with Ajax queries)

```
function show_cost_tables(costcenter){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/costcenter/' + costcenter,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        success: function(res){
              if(res.status === "success"){
                $('#costcenter_table').DataTable().clear();
                for(var i = 0; i < res.count; i++){
                    var entry = res.data[i];
                    var buttons = '<div style="text-align: center;"><button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary add-unit"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                                  '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning remove-unit"><span class="fa fa-minus"></span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                                  '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-load"><span class="fa fa-close"></span></button></div>';

                    $('#costcenter_table').DataTable().row.add([entry.name, entry.unit_count, entry.power_rating, entry.total_load, buttons]).draw();
                }

              } else {
                console.log(res.status + " login details.");
                $('#warning-login').modal('toggle');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### table.html (the input fields at the footer here should be gone and be replaced by that `Inline Edit` fields of `DataTables`)

```
<table id="costcenter_table" class="table table-bordered table-striped" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Load</th>
        <th>No. of Units</th>
        <th>Power Rating</th>
        <th>Total Load</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id ="costcenter_data">

  </tbody>
  <tfoot id="add-new-load" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <form id="new-load" role="form">
            <th><input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Load Name"><br><br><input id="brand" name="brand" type="text" placeholder="Brand"></th>
            <th><input id="unit_count" name="unit_count" type="text" placeholder="No. of Units"><br><br><input id="location" name="location" type="text" placeholder="Location"></th>
            <th><input id="power_rating" name="power_rating" type="text" placeholder="Power Rating"></th>
            <th><input id="total_load" placeholder="Total Load" type="text" disabled></th>
            <th><button id="add-load" class="btn btn-primary add-load" >Add New Load</button></th>
        </form>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>

</table>
```

**PS. Please try to ignore the last two input fields (Brand and Location), they are supposed to be dropdowns and browse buttons respectively.**

Comment: Any chance of showing us your code so far used in the screenshot?

Comment: Ah sorry forgot about that. Wait.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for the CSS used in the inline edit. If you click to edit in your [link](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple) you can right click in chrome to see the generated HTML. For me it generates something like: http://pastebin.com/raw/kySTQjcX I'd suggest replacing one of your inputs with all that code to see if it renders the look you're looking for. If it does, then you can narrow down on the CSS you're looking for.